# Is there a way to get 'access token' of adobe echo sign rest api v5 via email and password?

Tags: echosign

I want api access token via my echo sign account's login credential, and I don't want to redirect to echo sign login page for authorization.

Is it possible to get the api access token without redirecting to echo sign login page?

Note: In echo sign api v2, access token could be accessed via login and password but in api v5, I couldn't found any such end point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you give a try to "legacy access tokens"?

Comment: kindly check this, you might be looking for this, Integration token https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-acrobat-sign-discussions/how-to-use-the-integration-key/td-p/10853151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EchoSign OAuth workflow, provided below is the industry standard way of issuing Access Tokens and Refresh tokens for users by an Application and hence the v5 version of API only supports this. The v2 tokens end-point was deprecated after v2 in favour of this. If you are writing an application that works with EchoSign, please use Oauth and v5 as the recommended authentication mechanism

https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/static/oauthDoc.jsp

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the echosign api https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5 and click OAUTH ACCESS TOKEN button in any of the Try it out opperations. It will auto-generate an oauth token which you can copy and use externally. Best way ive worked out so far.